# Opening files in thread parallel with DASK + CFGrib is really slow

Tags: python, dask, cfgrib

I have been building up a GRIB file reading tool using the following code. I have heterogeneous files so I can't use the xarray.open_mfdatasets or anything like that.

```
def create_open_delays(file_list: List[str],expected_dataset_count:int) -> List[Delayed]:
    """
    This function runs through list of files and creates a
    list of delayed open commands.
    """
    return [
        dask.delayed(cfgrib.open_datasets,nout=expected_dataset_count)(file,
                                           backend_kwargs={
                                               "indexpath": ""
                                           },
                                           cache=True) for file in file_list
    ]
```

While running the code, I have noticed that running in Thread parallel had a 10X performance decrease compared to completely process parallel (each Dask worker has 1 thread only). I am guessing that this is to do with the GIL, no real surprises to anyone I guess. The DASK documentation does highlight this as an optimization opportunity. Having so many workers has some downsides as they now have a limited memory and it is extra overhead to start all of the workers, not to mention more process communication. Each task takes roughly 10 seconds so I am not concerned about the over head of Dask.delayed.

I have two questions:

1. Is there anything that can be done in the underling CFGrib/Eccodes packages that can improve multi-threading performance? From my vague understanding, numpy etc. takes steps in the underlying compiled code to release the GIL?
2. Is it possible to leverage the the new asyncIO python functionality in DASK? (I am not making demands of anyone to just develop this instantly, I am just interested to know if something like that exists or is in the works, whether it's a dumb idea)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already seen it, I recommend looking at Xarray, at least to see how they handle Grib.

Comment: The problem is I have heterogeneous Grib files. The xarray interface allows you to filter but it becomes quite inconvenient to do this 13 times. 

The xarray functions with CFGrib backend end up using more or less the same functions as their cfgrib counterparts, from my understanding of the source codes of xarray and CFGrib.   

Do you have any additional tips for the dask end? I could just go with 1 process per core, but the program will be training a neural network which would perform much better on multi-threaded. Is there a better way? 
Thanks for the tips :)